# ¿Cómo expresar en español "comfort food"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, comida, inglés

Según la Wikipedia (la entrada no tiene traducción al castellano), [*comfort food*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfort_food) es

> Food that provides a nostalgic or sentimental value to someone, and may be characterized by its high caloric nature, high carbohydrate level, or simple preparation.

Según otras fuentes es

> Food that provides consolation or a feeling of well-being, typically any with a high sugar or other carbohydrate content and associated with childhood or home cooking.
>
> Simple, home-style food that brings comforting thoughts of home or childhood. ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/comfort-food?s=t))

Con esta ambigua definición, dentro de la categoría "comfort food" podemos tener desde hamburguesas y perritos calientes hasta el simple sandwich de mantequilla de cacahuete. El que algo entre en esa categoría o no, puede depender de factores culturales.

Nunca se me habría ocurrido pensar que una buena paella valenciana o un potaje podrían ser tachados de *comfort food*, pues siempre pensé que el término se refería a esa comida que te satisface, aunque no sea la más sana. Observando la definición veo que, debido a lo evocativa que puede resultar una buena paella o una tortilla de patatas (posiblemente, lo que más echo de menos de España) estas también pueden denominarse "comfort food".

Algunas traducciones sugieren "Comida confortable", que para mí no tiene ningún sentido. "Reconfortante" podría acercarse un poco más, quizá para aquellas con más alto valor emocional que calórico. Por otro lado, los *mac & cheese* son comfort food para mi, no por su "valor emocional" pues jamás los comí de pequeño, pero sí por ser una de esas comidas no pesadas pero sí que te dejan bien satisfecho.

¿Cuál es la traducción más apropiada para "comfort food" en español?

Comment: Propongo *comida sencilla* para tu Mac and cheese, y *comida de nostalgia* o *comida de valor emocional* para tu paella.

Comment: No creo que haya una traducción exacta para eso, seguramente como propone @aparente001 tengamos que usar términos diferentes para cada caso. En [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=comfort) lo traducen como *comida casera*.

Comment: No creo que tengamos un equivalente a eso en español. El componente cultural en esta palabra es demasiado fuerte. Al menos en mi experiencia en SudAmerica, normalmente las comidas son caseras (como lo menciona  blonfu), requieren tiempo en su preparacion y tienen un cierto grado de elaboracion (contrario a una hamburguesa o un hotdog, o un "mac&cheese"). Resumiendo: casi todas las comidas en America Latina vienen a ser comfort food (creo que en España es la misma situacion, pero no he vivido allá para asegurarlo).

Comment: No creo que el tiempo de preparación o proceso de elaboración sea un factor importante. Un sandwich de mantequilla de cacachuete, pan con nocilla o pan tumaca tienen una fuerte asociación emocional/cultural. Un perrito caliente puede no requerir tanto tiempo de preparación pero un "mac&cheese" sí. Incluso un perrito caliente tiene, por cierto, su proceso de elaboración. Piensa en una barbacoa de _Independence day_, donde hay que encender la barbacoa, al perrito se le ponen mil condimentos, etc (esa es la asociación emocional: la fiesta, comida en familia, etc)

Comment: Perdón, tengo que aclarar más precisamente lo que yo entiendo por *comfort food*.  *Comfort food* es lo que preparas (rápido o lento -- la complejidad no tiene importancia) cuando llegas a la casa rendido o amolado por algo; y después de preparar y consumir esa comida, empiezas a sentirte mejor.  Después de todo, el concepto se basa en la definición de *comfort*.

Comment: I agree with @aparente001 here. For me comfort food is something which comforts you in the same sense of to comfort as when someone comforts you when you are upset about something.

Comment: La cómida *comfort* *par excellence* en España tendría que ser las croquetas más que incluso la tortilla.  Lo que pasa es que *comfort food* se interpreta simultáneamente como comida nostálgica y comida satisfaciente.  Pero es difícil usar nostálgica porque se supone que es algo que ya no tienes, que obviamente no es el caso cuando podemos ir a comprar croquetas cuando nos dé la gana

Comment: @guifa Gracias por la reflexión, creo que das en el clavo sobre lo de que es "nostálgica y satisfaciente" a la vez. De ahí la dificultad de encontrar un término apropiado para traducir. Sobre lo de que podemos comprar croquetas cuando nos de la gana, ójala. Yo en Boston sí he encontrado donde comprar chorizo (que hecho más de menos que el jamón serrano) y la tortilla de patatas no me importa hacerla.  Con lo de las croquetas, me has creado una especie de "morriña gastronómica" que no me había dado cuenta que tenía.

Comment: puede ser comida típica

Comment: **aparent001 tiene razón**. Aqui se le mucha equivocación, lo lamento. comfort aqui es consuelo. No hay duda ninguna.

Answer (score 7):

Me temo que en español ese término es intraducible. Solemos sentirnos apegados/cómodos a la **comida que nos hacía nuestra madre de pequeños** o a alguna "**guarrada**" (fast food, comida muy grasienta sin valor nutritivo), que asociamos con momentos festivos o familiares, pero creo que no tenemos una palabra para describir esa sensación de "*comida con la que me siento cómodo*"...

Quizá sea porque a la hora de sentarnos a la mesa somos un poco aventureros y disfrutamos de la buena comida, sea algo que probamos por primera vez o todo un clásico en nuestra memoria culinaria... Así como en otros países carecen de un término para "**merendar**" o "**sobremesa**", formas y fases de la comida que en nuestro país tienen mucha importancia :)

Comment: Por lo de "guarradas" me imagino que eres española. En Chile a esa comida le decimos "chatarra". ¿Usan también la palabra "chatarra" en España para hablar de pizzas, etc.?

Comment: @Rodrigo no, al menos yo nunca lo he oído. _Chatarra_ lo usamos solamente para restos de electrodomésticos o coches. Usamos _guarradas_, _porquerías_ y similares, todo siempre en relación al cerdito interno que nos lleva a comer cosas así.

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo, gracias por el comentario. Sí, en efecto soy española :) Como dice fedorqui aquí no usamos chatarra con esa acepción (pero es graciosa, me la apunto). Ay, el cerdito interno <3

Comment: Se ve claramente el problema aqui en que el inglés no se entendió. Lamento. Es verdad. Todas ideas se traducen. Aqui comfort es consuelo y nada tiene que ver con comodidad.

Answer (score 4):

La palabra **comfort** en inglés en éste contexto es **consuelo**, y no comodidad.

> **Alimentos consuelo** La tristeza puede fomentar una mala alimentación debido al deseo de tener un breve estado de euforia

Por NÚRIA LLAVINA RUBIO miércoles 18 julio de 2007

[alimentos consuelo](https://www.consumer.es/alimentacion/alimentos-consuelo.html)

> Comer para olvidar: ante un desequilibrio emocional buscamos consuelo
> en la comida

EFENOTICIA 07.03.2013 - 14:07H

[consuelo](https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/1751462/0/comer-para-olvidar/atracon/gula/)

La comida o los alimentos considerados "de consuelo" pueden ser qualquier alimento o comida en la medida que es la persona que la consume que dice que es "comfort" para él o ella. No se define "del exterior".

Comment: It is interesting to speculate on what would have happened if the OP had asked for a translation of _comfort eating_ which might have suggested _consuelo_ much more quickly. It is clearly the best suggestion.

Comment: @mdewey In over the almost 30 years I have participated in online groups where translation is the thing, people react oddly when non-native speakers disagree with native speakers. Or when native speakers (here, of Spanish) make a translation error. The reaction is silence.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que estuve leyendo, lo equivalente en español, está más asociado a la comida rápida, calórica. Aquí en Argentina también la llamamos, como bien dicen arriba, *comida chatarra*.

Tenemos que tener en cuenta que los estadounidenses no tienen una cultura culinaria tan desarrollada como la española, o la de los países latinoamericanos. Por esa razón, cuando se refieren a "confortable", no tienen la misma asociación que nosotros a esa palabra en relación a la comida, ya que como bien dicen anteriormente, nuestros recuerdos de comida nostálgica están más relacionados con comidas elaboradas por nuestras madres y abuelas con recetas bien desarrolladas.
Creo que le llaman así a la posibilidad de ir a comer rico, rápido y barato.
Aquí un resumen de un restaurant que propone esta comida.

"prepared with simple, common ingredients, which only as a whole composition gives the pleasure and satiety that amateurs of comfort food classics – pizza and burgers – are craving for.

"preparado con ingredientes simples y comunes, que solo como una composición completa brindan el placer y la saciedad que ansían los aficionados a los clásicos de la comida reconfortante - las hamburguesas y la pizza.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con fast food.

Answer (score 2):

El término parece aludir a cualquier alimento que nos haga sentir bien, lo cual es altamente subjetivo y sujeto a un amplio abanico de variaciones culinarias regionales (desde el punto de vista gastronómico). Propongo que una acepción posible sería

> ***platos o alimentos reconfortantes***

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo con algunos autores, se trata de un mecanismo psicológico de respuesta, que se produce en el [**síndrome de alimentación nocturna** (SAN)](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADndrome_de_alimentaci%C3%B3n_nocturna).

De acuerdo con ello, **comfort food** se puede traducir como "**comida de alivio**" o "**comida de recompensa**".

En alguna ocasión, la "comfort food" se ha llegado a [comparar con el **Prozac**](https://www.salon.com/2011/06/23/comfort_food_psychology/), un conocido antidepresivo.

De hecho, a las personas aquejadas de este síndrome se les suele administrar precisamente un antidepresivo, la **sertralina**.

Otra cuestión aparte es el marketing:

[image: Portada del libro "Comfort food, de James Oliver]

Answer (score 1):

¿Comida que da consuelo? ¿Comida "de consuelo"? ¿Comida de buenos recuerdos?

El inglés es mi idioma materno y el español mi segundo idioma. No sé si estas sugerencias sirven o no, pero es lo que interpreto con mi idea de "comfort food".

Comment: Mira mi respuesta: en ella doy pistas precisamente sobre tus dudas.

Answer (score 0):

En mi país, a esta comida que da abrigo emocional, consuela y reconforta, es decir, renueva fuerzas, se le dice: comida casera.

Comment: Comida casera sería "homemade food". Aunque la comida casera puede tener algunas de estas cualidades de la _comfort food_ son dos cosas distintas. La _comfort food_ no es necesariamente comida casera. La comida casera tampoco es necesariamente _comfort food_ (por ejemplo, un plato de nutritivas pero insípidas judías verdes con patatas. No tiene ese componente emocional o nostálgico)

Comment: No es un tipo de comida. Es una comida que comes por el efecto que te hace. La comida esa es diferente para cada persona...

Comment: Así es, @Lambie: en mi respuesta hago hincapié en el verdadero significado de la *comfort food*.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to translate that expression and I used 'Comidas ricas y llamativas' after reading a little bit. Hope this helps.