# "Cocina de Familia" as something made by a family or tradition

Tags: solicitud-de-término, chile

My wife and I are in the food business and planing to make it more professional, including a Facebook and Instagram pages. For that I'll invest in some professional logo and brand name.

I'm looking for a word or expression that may translate the fact that the food we're selling is made by a family business, with all the love and quality that you may expect from a meal cooked by your grandmother.

I was wondering if "Cocina de Familia" is the best choice here. I google it and it seems there's a TV show with that name.

Just a note: I'm a brazilian (therefore portuguese speaker) living in Chile with a very poor spanish.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a good choice. The term "comida casera" would describe the type of food you refer to but is too common to be used as a fancy name.

Comment: As a question this is off-topic here ☹, but as a name for you business sounds fine to me 

Comment: @DGaleano How can this be off topic?

Comment: "comida casera" or "cocina casera" but it's not clear if your question is asking for a suitable name for your business or a term to describe what you're offering.

Comment: @aris I'm looking for a word or expression that may translate the fact that the food we're selling is made by a family business, with all the love and quality that you may expect from a meal cooked by your grandmother.

Comment: Croves, it can be consider off topic if people think it is unclear what you are asking for (like, do you think that is a term in English for that, like [comfort food](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21843/5481)) or if they think that there are multiple possible answers to this question, all equally valid (except for your personal preference). The "off-topicness of a question might sometimes be a subjective thing. If you need extra help understanding what to do to make the question more on-topic (or if it gets closed and you disagree0 yo can bring the conversation to Meta.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: "Cocina de tradicion familiar"
This means you are cooking recipes that have been passed through generations.

When you call it "Cocina casera", it means homemade food...
The meaning is a bit different. Cause it can be anything really. And generally something simple.

Answer (score 1):

There are two concepts at stake in your intended message, which are closely related but not exactly the same. Why not to appeal for both meanings?

> Cocina casera / Recetas de familia

('Cocina casera', for homemade food every-day cooking, to convey [an artisan style](https://www.thekitchn.com/what-does-artisan-mean-to-you-174439) of preparation; 'Recetas de familia, to allude to comfort food that has a tradition of excellence passed on by generations)

PS: This is something general, as I'm from Argentina, so you may need to check  locally to assure a 100% fit